# JsonArrayRequest wont activate onResponse

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

Im currently trying to read images from my MySQL database that is sitting at my localhost.

The database includes path to images that I would like to read and show on listview.

However, for some reason it is not entering into onResponse and it skips immediately to 'requestQueue'.

The class is as follows:

```
package com.example.customlistview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String HI = "https://10.0.2.2/customlistview/productinfo.php";
    ArrayList<Product_List>product;
    ListView lv;
    private JsonArrayRequest request;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

        product=new ArrayList<>();


        getData();
    }

    private void getData() {
        request=new JsonArrayRequest(HI, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                for (int i=0; i<response.length(); i++){
                    try {
                        jsonObject=response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Product_List productList=new Product_List(jsonObject.getString("product_name"),
                                jsonObject.getString("product_price"),
                                jsonObject.getString("product_img"));
                        product.add(productList);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                setupData(product);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);

    }

    private void setupData(ArrayList<Product_List> product) {
        adapter=new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_list,product);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Is there a reason for it to skip the for loop and all the reading of the database and returning request = null?

I tested the php file using ARC and it all worked good.
Thank you

Comment: that's how asynchronous code works. It is called *a callback*. `onResponse` will be called *later* when the request completes. Please make sure you know Java basics before you proceed with Android.